# How to debug linux startup hang

Tags: linux, boot, debugging, systemctl

My ubuntu system hangs on the startup. It hangs on [OK] items like usual on boot. Interestingly, I am able to ssh onto this machine, but the boot never finishes and login screen doesn't appear. What should I do to debug the problem?

Comment: Check dmesg in the minimum to see for a potential error, and you dont state on what line it get stuck on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can log in to the system, you can use `systemctl` to find any units that are hanging or failed to start correctly. For example:

```
systemctl list-units --state activating,reloading,failed
```

What you do next depends on the specific units that are having a problem. In general you would look at their journal entries/logs to see if a problem is obvious.